# Homeomorphism or not?

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

> **Problem**: Let $f:X \rightarrow Y$ and $g:Y \rightarrow Z$ where $X,Y$ and $Z$ are metric spaces. If $g \circ f$ is homeomorphism and $f$ is surjective prove that $f$ and $g$ are homeomorphism.

The problem I could not solve but I prove that $f,g$ are bijective. So, if $f$ and $g$ are continuous then $f^{-1}$ and $g^{-1}$ are continuous because :

$$ (g \circ f)^{-1} = f^{-1} \circ g^{-1} \implies f^{-1}=(g \circ f)^{-1}\circ g \wedge g^{-1}=f \circ (g\circ f)^{-1} $$

My question is whether the result can be proven without assuming that $f$ and $g$ are continuous. If so, I would like help because I have not been able to prove it. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The claim is false without the assumption that $f$ and $g$ are continuous. Here is a counterexample:

Let $f,g :\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ be defined as 
$$f(x)=g(x)= \left\{ 
\begin{array}{lc}
x &\mbox{ if } x \in \mathbb{Q} \\
-x&\mbox{ if } x \notin \mathbb{Q} 
\end{array}
\right.$$

Then, $f$ is surjective and $g \circ f(x)=x \forall x \in \mathbb R$ is a homemorphism. But $f,g$ are not.

Comment: Simple and clear example!

Comment: Good example! thanks